# The correct way to ignore log entries with NLog at runtime

Tags: c#, nlog

I create a `MongoTarget` at runtime to the server that's hosting the production database. What's the correct way to ignore unwanted log entries at runtime? I'm currently creating a `MemoryTarget` and creating a rule to send the unwanted log entries to that with `Final = true`, which works but feels pretty hacky. What should I be doing?

```
    var memoryTarget = new MemoryTarget
    {
        Name = "memory",
        MaxLogsCount = 100
    };

    var rule = new LoggingRule("Microsoft.*", LogLevel.Trace, LogLevel.Info, memoryTarget) { Final = true };
    config.LoggingRules.Add(rule);
```

I've tried adding a ConditionBasedFilter, but this seems to ignore everything.

```
    rule.Filters.Add(new ConditionBasedFilter()
    {
        Condition = "starts-with(logger, 'Microsoft')",
        Action = FilterResult.Ignore
    });
```

**Complete Code With Answer From [Rolf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77192584/654070)**

```
    private void SetUpLogging(string connectionString)
    {
        var mongoTarget = new MongoTarget
        {
            Name = "mongolog",
            ConnectionString = connectionString,
            CollectionName = "ApiLog",
            IncludeDefaults = true,
            IncludeEventProperties = true,
            DatabaseName = "Log",
            CappedCollectionSize = 20000000
        };

        LogManager.Setup().LoadConfiguration(c =>
        {
            c.ForLogger("Microsoft.*").WriteToNil(LogLevel.Warn); 
            c.ForLogger().FilterMinLevel(LogLevel.Debug).WriteTo(mongoTarget);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NLog v5 allows you to do this:

```cs
LogManager.Setup().LoadConfiguration(c =>
{
   c.ForLogger("Microsoft.*").WriteToNil(LogLevel.Warn); // FinalMinLevel
   c.ForLogger().FilterMinLevel(LogLevel.Info).WriteTo(mongoTarget);
});
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Fluent-Configuration-API

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-Rules-FinalMinLevel

Comment: Yeah, Serilog has Config you can use Overrides: `"Serilog": {
      "MinimumLevel": {
        "Default": "Information",
        "Override": {
          "Microsoft": "Warning",
          "System": "Error"
        }
      }`

Comment: That removes many lines of code which is never a bad thing! Thanks